# altair outputs "ufunc 'isinf' not supported for the input types" error, when matplotlib does not

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, altair

I have such a pandas DataFrame:

```
RangeIndex: 4478 entries, 0 to 4477
Data columns (total 11 columns):
 #   Column                          Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------                          --------------  -----         
 0   timestamp                       4478 non-null   datetime64[ns]
 1   user                            4478 non-null   object        
 2   Active_energy_exported_kWh      2466 non-null   float64       
 3   Active_energy_imported_kWh      4473 non-null   float64       
 4   Reactive_energy_imported_kVARh  3822 non-null   float64       
 5   Reactive_energy_imported_kVARh  3822 non-null   float64       
 6   Active_power_imported_kW        4449 non-null   float64       
 7   Reactive_power_imported_kVAR    4471 non-null   float64       
 8   Apparent_power_imported_kVA     4471 non-null   float64       
 9   Power_factor                    4449 non-null   float64       
 10  Supply_frequency_Hz             4449 non-null   float64       
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(9), object(1)
memory usage: 385.0+ KB
```

Now if I try and plot this with `altair` this way:

```py
ttChart = alt.Chart(mlogs).mark_line().encode(
    alt.X('timestamp:T', title=None),
    alt.Y('Supply_frequency_Hz:Q', title=None),
)
```

I get `TypeError: ufunc 'isinf' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''`

But when I do

```py
mlogs.plot(x="timestamp", y="Supply_frequency_Hz")
```

I can see what I expect.

For what I can see, types are correct, I cannot see what's happening.

Comment: Could you create a reproducible example by uploading your data (or a small subset of it that recreates the issue)? It seems like you might have zeroes in your data and have logged it which creates the infinite values. I am not sure why it doesn't work in one of the cases, but would need to check test with the data.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/2KdDuVJQ here. Thanks!

Comment: When I use `pd.read_csv()` to load the file you linked to and then run your code, I don't see any error.

Comment: you're right.
When I look at the complete dump (4.5k lines), I see stuff like this:
`2021-02-09 20:32:29,021329fd3488689f3144cd0095308d9114427ad4f7e4a15c52513410f091240879,,,,,,,,,` which I think is the problem to solve.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/wtU7S5ST this should be useful to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Still no error using that data. If you want help on this, I suggest you attempt to create a self-contained [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (i.e. a code snippet that does not rely on any external data sources) that reproduces the problem, and edit your question to add that.

Comment: Just FYK. I actually read a table from a db, and fill a dataframe with the fetched rows. As can be seen by the `.info()` message, it seems to be fine. But when I try and operate on it, I face different problems. I then tried to dump the df to a `csv` and read it back, and everything works. I think the problem is creating the dataset with the data returned from the db then, but I'm going to address it lately, since it's data exploration time now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the same error message. It turned out that 2 columns in my DataFrame had the same name. Fixing that, solved the problem.

Two columns in your example are named 'Reactive_energy_imported_kVARh'. Maybe that is is the reason for the error.